# C loop throws error unless printf() included?

Tags: c, printf

I have a function in C:

```
int concanatedProduct(int n, int x, int size)
{
    char numberString[10];
    long arr[size];
    int cnt = 0;

    long product = 0;
    int digit = n;
    while (digit!=0) {

        product = x * (digit % 10); // Multiply by last digit
        arr[cnt] = product; // add to array
        cnt++; // increment count
        digit /= 10; // chop off last dig

    }

    for (int i=size-1; i>=0; i--) { // reverse the number to make it the right way
        //printf("%ld", arr[i]);
        sprintf(numberString, "%s%ld",numberString, arr[i]);
    }

        return atoi(numberString);
}
```

It works fine when I use it outside a loop. However when I try and put it in a for loop it throws SIGBART error unless I include printf.

This works:

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        x = concanatedProduct(12, i, 2);
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
```

This throws an error:

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        x = concanatedProduct(12, i, 2);
    }
```

What on earth is going on? It's got me completely stumped.

Comment: I don't think it's safe to use the string as the destination and a parameter in sprintf...  What should your example result in and what do you see when it works?

Comment: You use `numberString` without initializing it.

Comment: It's for a Project Euler problem - http://projecteuler.net/problem=38. When I use it like this: concanatedProduct(123, 192, 3); it returns 192384576. So I want to loop through a bunch of numbers, generate these concatenated products and then check if they are pandigital.

Comment: You're right Musa that was the problem!

Comment: @Musa:  (If you make your comment an answer, I can upvote it.)

Comment: Yup, if Musa posts an answer I'll accept it. Thanks Musa!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first call to `sprintf` `numberString` is not initialized, resulting in such behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Section 7.19.6.6 of the C99 standard says:

> The sprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output
>   is written into an array (specified by the argument s) rather than to
>   a stream. A null character is written at the end of the characters
>   written; it is not counted as part of the returned value. *If copying
>   takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.*

The italicised sentence means that even if `numberString` is initialised, the line:

```
sprintf(numberString, "%s%ld", numberString, arr[i]);
```

has undefined behavior.